# find first 3 working days in microsoft managment studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column 'working days' which give info is it working day or no (1 for woking day and 0 for weekend). And the task is to find first  3 working days in each month.

I try to use this code:

```
 SELECT working_day, *
  FROM table 
  WHERE tdate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, -1, GETDATE()), 0))
  AND working_day = 1
  AND tdate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

Comment: 'I try to use this code:' -and what happen?

Comment: It seems that you are using SQL Server, not MySQL!

Comment: "mysql managment studio" - what is it? Maybe you mean "microsoft sql managment studio"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `row_number` function as the following:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(tdate), MONTH(tdate) ORDER BY tdate) RN
  FROM tbl_name
WHERE working_day = 1
)
SELECT tdate, working_day
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN <= 3
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ef-pc9ml)